# Why is my NULL count returning 0 in MySQL? Very basic

Tags: mysql

I have an 2 easy questions that are puzzling me (I am new to Mysql)

I have a table (survey) with 3 columns, UserID (primary), SkinColor, and HairColor. I wanted to count the number of people who have a hair color that is null (they didn't answer the survey).

I did this with:

```
select count(id)
from survey
where haircolor is null
```

But I was puzzled why I couldn't do

```
select count(haircolor)
from survey
where haircolor is null
```

It returned 0. Why is this?

Question 2: I want to return the total number of survey respondents (all ID's), number of people with null value for hair color, and null value for skin color. I tried this query

```
select count(id), count(skincolor), count(haircolor)
from survey
where skincolor is null and haircolor is null
```

But that just returned the the count where skincolor and haircolor are both null obviously, and not an individual count for each column. Is there a way to put the WHERE constraint up in the SELECT section so I can specify different constraints for each select?

Thanks!

Comment: Q1: Use `select count(1) from ...`, it's faster and doesn't have the null problem.  Q2: It seems to me that you have the germ of the answer to question 2 in your first question.  How about `select count(1), count(skincolor), count(haircolor) from survey;`?

Answer (score 2):

I did this with:

> select count(id)
>   from survey
>   where haircolor is null

But I was puzzled why I couldn't do

> select count(haircolor)
>   from survey
>   where haircolor is null

It worked the first time because the first time you are counting the ID's where X is null and the IS's themselves are not null. The second time you are counting the things that are themselves NULL and the COUNT of things that are NULL is 0.

Answer (score 0):

As for question 2:

It is easy enough, since COUNT(null) is 0:

```
 select count(id), count(skincolor), count(haircolor) from survey
```

This gives you the number of non-nulls for each column.

You should also be able to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT count(1) AS num, 
       count(1)-count(skincolor) AS nullcolor, 
       count(1)-count(haircolor) AS nullhair 
    FROM survey
```

Answer (score 0):

for the second case:

```
select 'No haircolor', count(id)
from survey
where haircolor is null
union all 
select 'no skincolor',count(id)
from survey
where skincolor is null
```

this should return something like:

```
No haircolor   3
No skincolor   1
```

If you want the result as a single line you'll need to do a pivot on the result above.

Note: I'm assuming String literals are quoted with single quotes as in MsSql